# Storing data against a user who does not log in?

Tags: php, html

On my website users do not log in, yet they can interact with the site. For example, they can vote on categories.

What would be the best way to prevent a user (even though they are not logged in) from voting for the same category more than once.

My initial thought was to store a user's IP address, when they vote, their IP along with the category voted for is stored in my database. Voting again for the same category will not have any effect.

I know proxies etc can circumnavigate this, but it's only meant to be a casual system to fool basic users.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Anything, with enough effort, can be manipulated. As you said, the IP address can be changed by using a proxy. Everything else about the browser (user agent, installed fonts, OS, etc) come from the client, so these should not be relied on either.

Answer (score 0):

You can start a session with [session_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) and use AJAX to store vote information in the session. Similarly you can use AJAX call to your PHP script to see if a user can vote or not.

One downside to that is that if user removes his PHPSESSID cookie your `session_start()` will create new session, to avoid that you should use your own session control, any way you like, though it would have to store more unique information such as `user-agent` and the IP address as well as PHPSESSID.

**Note, without any heavy counter-measures this can be fooled, one way or another, but you said yourself *it's only meant to be a casual system to fool basic users*.**

Answer (score 0):

If users do not login (do not authenticate themselves) on the site - then there is no 100% reliable way.

To my opinion, the best would be to use cookies(). for each user store in the cookie list of categories he has already voted, and deny a vote, if he retries.

But please note that if the guy cleans his cookies or come from another comupter - he will be able to vote again...

Again - there is no 100% reliable way

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be storing a cookie:

```
setcookie("user_voted", "1", time()+86400); // good for a day
```

Then:

```
if ($_COOKIE["user_voted"] == "1") {
    echo "You already voted!";
}
```

Not bullet proof, but you mentioned casual to fool basic users - that should do the trick then.

Answer (score 0):

the two best solutions are either ip or cookies. but they are not 100% reliable